# Undefined Reference Errors with libssl and libcrypto

Tags: android, openssl, libssl, libcrypto, fortify-source

I'm working on an Android platform build with android-4.4_r1 (KRT16S).  I can compile the source (it's a big project) into a *.so file without any trouble.

If I try to build the source into a command line executable with `include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)` (basically just wrapping the library with a command line interface), I run into the following errors when linking:

```
out/target/product/flo/obj/lib/libssl.so: error: undefined reference to '__strlen_chk'
out/target/product/flo/obj/lib/libssl.so: error: undefined reference to '__strchr_chk'
out/target/product/flo/obj/lib/libcrypto.so: error: undefined reference to '__strrchr_chk'
out/target/product/flo/obj/lib/libcrypto.so: error: undefined reference to '__sprintf_chk'
out/target/product/flo/obj/lib/libcrypto.so: error: undefined reference to '__strcat_chk'
```

I've seen reference to this problem [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/9do2ELH1rBU/p6DRJ3ghx94J) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057805/ndk-build-throwing-error-relating-to-libcrypto-so), but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Do I need to build openssl differently to work in the executable?

**Update**

This is how I built openssl:

- repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.4_r1.2
- repo sync
- source build/envsetup.sh
- lunch full_flo-eng
- cd into the openssl directory
- mm -B

I didn't follow any outside directions.  I just used what was provided in the repo.

Comment: `__strlen_chk` is part of `FORTIFY_SOURCE`. How did you build OpenSSL? Did you follow the instructions at [OpenSSL and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android)? Show at least one compile command with `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc`. Are you using `ANDROID_SYSROOT`?

Comment: I built the openssl that was part of android-4.4_r1.  No special options, just used mmma on my project.  I'm not sure whether or not I'm using ANDROID_SYSROOT (new to Android).

Answer (score 2):

Try set `D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` when building. I've solved this with libcurl, with details in the last part here http://qiankanglai.me/misc/2014/08/31/android-libcurl/